# Flex: Change global Date formatting?

Tags: apache-flex, formatting, global

Is there a way to change the Flex global Date/Time formatting, so once changed to apply to the whole application ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [use `DateTimeFormatter`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/formatters/DateTimeFormatter.html#methodSummary) in cooperation with [localization](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS19f279b149e7481c-1c03f02c12bd00c4763-8000.html#WS19f279b149e7481c7370eb2d12bd013e888-7fff) (with resource bundles). To change dates formatting just change current locale or change [the value of `locale` style](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/globalization/supportClasses/GlobalizationBase.html#style%3alocale) for formatter class. Something like that.